# cocos2d-x physics nodes slide along other

Tags: cocos2d-x, physics, chipmunk

I am developing a game using cocos2d-x with built-in physics engine. In this game, user try to put object as stack and keep them balance.

However, i got a problem when i try to put an object on other one, it makes two objects slide along each other

I tried set friction value but nothing changes. I noticed that when i put a dynamic object on a non-dynamic object it's fine but when i put a dynamic object on other dynamic object, the problem (sliding along) will be happened.

I also create a gif demonstrate my problem because of my bad English.
http://makeagif.com/i/0lSVdW

Sorry i don't have enough reputation to post images.
I would appreciate any help!